# Django TypeError: 'Library' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I'm upgrading code to the latest version of Django Version: 3.1.2

```
from django.template import Variable, Library
register = Library()

def striplinebreaks(value, arg):
    """
    Removes all values of arg from the given string.
    """
    safe = isinstance(value, SafeData)
    value = value.replace('\n', u'').replace('\r', u'').replace('\t', u'')
    if safe and arg != ';':
        return mark_safe(value)
    return value


register('striplinebreaks')
```

getting this error

```
File "/home/sam/code/kpsga/lamusoftware/generic/templatetags/striplinebreaks.py", line 18, in <module>
    register(striplinebreaks)
TypeError: 'Library' object is not callable
```

Comment: If you're meaning to *register a filter*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters

Comment: register is not a callable, you should use register.filter or similar, like mentioned in the docs in the comment above.

Comment: You can `register.filter('striplinebreaks')`, not `register(..)`.

Comment: Use: `register.filter('striplinebreaks',striplinebreaks)`

Comment: They really should call it "registry" in the docs, cause people often make this mistake, since it's a verb and there's also `admin.register()`.